# Function Call Error

Tags: c++, function

So far, my code all works correctly except for the function Pelly. It does not return the AdjustedGross like it is suppose to.   im very sure the math is correct, i think the problem is with how the function is called. im not too good with functions. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double Federal = 0, PellGrant = 5730, AdjustedGross = 0, Total = 0;
    int YesNo;
    int const StaffordLoan = 9500;

    cout << "Let me forecast your FAFSA" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your adjusted Gross income: " << endl; cin >> AdjustedGross;

    if (AdjustedGross >= 30000)
    {
        cout << "Sorry, your income is too high for this forecaster";
        return 0;
    }

    cout << "Can someone claim you as a dependent? [1 = yes / 0 = no]: " << endl; cin >> YesNo;
    if (YesNo == 1)
    {
        PellGrant -= 750;
    }

    Federal = 1465;
    if (AdjustedGross >= 19000)
    {
        cout << "I'm sorry, but the Work-Study Award is not available to you" << endl;
        Federal = 0;
    }

    double Pelly(AdjustedGross);

    Total = Federal + StaffordLoan + PellGrant;

    if (Federal != 0)
    {
        cout << "Your Work-Study Award (if available): " << Federal << endl;
    }
    cout << "Your Stafford Loan award (if needed): " << StaffordLoan << endl;
    cout << "Your Pell Grant: " << PellGrant << endl;

    return (0);
}

double  Pelly(double x)
{
    // x is AdjustedGross
    if ((x > 12000) && (x < 20000)) // make sure adjusted gross is bettween 12000 & 20000
    {
        double a = x / 1000; // for every 1000 in adjusted, subtract 400
            a *= 400;
        x -= a;
    }

    if (x > 20000) // check adjusted > 20000
    {
        double  a = x / 1000; // for every 1000 in adjusted, subtract 500
        a *= 500;
        x -= a;
    }
    return x;
}
```

Comment: You aren't actually calling the function anywhere. Better read a good introductory C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

Make:

```
double Pelly(AdjustedGross);
```

into:

```
double foo = Pelly(AdjustedGross);
```

to store the value returned from `Pelly` in the `double` variable `foo`.
Use forward declaration on function `Pelly`, in other words declare it like so before `main`:

```
double Pelly(double);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually assign the result of the function to a variable and then use this result. So you should do something like:

```
double pellyResult = Pelly(AdjustedGross);
```

You should also make sure you declare your function above main:

```
double pellyResult(double);
```

Answer (score 1):

Signature of your method should either be

```
void Pelly(double& AdjustedGross)
```

i.e. without return value at all (that way, AdjustedGross is passed by reference and modified directly inside the function, calling the function would then be

```
Pelly(AdjustedGross);
```

or your function call should be

```
double foo = Pelly(AdjustedGross)
```

as stated in the other answers.